# optimize repetitive coefficients evaluation

Tags: c++, optimization, parallel-processing

I'm solving 3 different linear equations systems, where each system depends on the results of the previous one. They all share some coefficients, which then together with the previous results define the new system (except the first one which is defined by its own of course).

The code is somewhat like this:

```
vector<double>point(n);//initialized to values
vector<double>A(n*n,0);
vector<double>b(n,0);
double coefficient;

for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
  for(int j=0;j<n;j++){
  coefficient=myCoeff(point[i],point[j]);
    //A[i+j*n] and b[j] initialized using coefficient
  }
}

vector<double>x(n) //initialized as solution of A\b

for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
  for(int j=0;j<n;j++){
  coefficient=myCoeff(point[i],point[j]);
    //A[i+j*n] and b[j] initialized using coefficient and x
  }
}
//x=A\b
//and so on for the third system
```

Profiling the code shows that 80% of the time is used calling myCoeff. Optimize myCoeff is beyond my interests.

I have two options in my mind: 
-write coefficient to a file once and read it twice
-use parallel_for instead of the outer for loop.

Is it possible to combine these two options?
Any other suggestion is welcome, if you need more details about the code I can provide them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using parallel_for to parallelize the loops (either the outer one or both) looks like a good idea since calls to myCoeff seem to be expensive.

However, writing all coefficients to the filesystem might not be a very good idea since filesystem I/O tend to be very expensive and to disrupt the execution flow of your program. If you can pay an extra n*n storage, it might be better to store coefficients in memory :

```
vector<double> coeff(n*n, 0);
for (i...) {
  for (j...) {
    coeff[j+n*i] = myCoeff(point[i],point[j]);
  }
}
```

This can easily be combined with the loops parallelization.

If you stick to your idea of storing coefficients in the filesystem (maybe to reduce memory usage), using only one file makes parallelization very difficult (files are meant to be accessed sequencially). Instead, you might want to create a file per line in the matrix. That way, you can easily combine the coefficients storage with the parallelization of the outer loop.

Also, you might be better off storing your matrix coefficients by line : A[i*n+j] or inverting your i and j loops.

Comment: I was actually considering this approach. The coefficients are in reality 4, so that would make 5*n*n and the max n would be around 0.4-0.5 of what is now but might be enough. About the index of A you're right, I did that at first and during subsequent corrections things got messy.

Comment: @MarcoS if you have multiple coefficients and you store them in memory, be sure to group together all 4 coefficients related to the same (i,j) pair (for example grouping them in a struct and storing a vector<struct>), instead of having one n*n matrix for each coefficient.

Comment: Maybe you know also this, myCoeff is from a dll. Is that ok for parallel_for? I can compile myCoeff if needed.

Comment: @MarcoS it's OK for `myCoeff` to reside in a dll. The only requirement for `myCoeff` is that it must be thread-safe.